# How to navigate between views with glade and pygobject?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, glade, pygobject

i'm developing a simple applications with GTK glade and python,
what i need to do is to navigate between some "views", i explain, i have a "home" view from which i can go to 2 different views called "Info" and "Datas",
i can't find a way to do that. I need to implement a sort of mobile navigation so when i click on info all content of the window have to go away and the info content have to be shown. 
By now i can handle the clicks on the buttons but i have no idea and i can't find some tutorials or docs on how to make some navigation without tabs or similar things.

```
__________________________
|          HOME          |
||--------|     |-------||
||  Info  |     | Datas ||
||--------|     |-------||
|________________________| 

__________________________
|          INFO          |
||--------|              |
||  Back  |              |
||--------|              |
|________________________|
```

Comment: Are you using GTK+ 2 or GTK+ 3?

Comment: I'm using GTK3+

Comment: Then you're not using pytgtk (for GTK+ 2), you're using pygobject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [GtkStack](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Stack.html) to handle your home/info transition.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this method:

- Created on glade a GtkWindow (with home layout) and a GtkBox with menu layout, then i stored then into two variables called **menu_lay** and **home_lay** using the [builder.get_object()](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Builder.html#Gtk.Builder.get_object) function
- Written a clear window function:

  ```
  def clear_window(self):
      for childn in self.window.get_children():
          self.window.remove(childn)
  ```
- When the menu button is clicked i clear the window, add the menu layout and then invoke the **show_all()** method on window widget

  ```
  def clk_menu(self,event):
      self.clear_window()
      self.window.add(self.menu_lay)
      self.window.show_all()
  ```
- vice versa when clicking the back button i clear window and add the home layout

  ```
  def clk_back(self,event):
      self.clear_window()
      self.window.add(self.home_l)
      self.window.show_all()
  ```

i don't know if it's the best way to do that, but it works as well for now.

Anyway if you have other ideas, way of handle this or suggestions please answer!

[[EDIT]]

This method works but it works better with GtkStack as suggested by 
liberforce, that allows to have smooth transition!

Comment: Use a GtkStack like @liberforce recommended, you will find it is way better.

Comment: Ok, i'll give a try!